# Android Runnable won't repeat

Tags: java, android, multithreading, runnable

I wan't to refresh a list of website every X Minutes.

After reading this thread: [nested postDelayed / Runnable / Handler Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11197543/nested-postdelayed-runnable-handler-android)

I decided to use a Runnable + Handler instead of a TimerTask.
Unfortunately my Runnable won't run a second time. It will refresh the data once, then nothing happens.

my onCreate() Method looks like this:

```
...    
fooWebsitesListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.fooWebsitesListView);

fooWebsitesAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<fooWebsite>(
    getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list_black_text,
    R.id.list_content, websiteList);

    fooWebsitesListView.setAdapter(fooWebsitesAdapter);
    final fooWebsitesActivity fooWebsitesRefreshActivity = new fooWebsitesActivity();

    mHandler = new Handler();

    refreshfooWebsitesRunnable = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.d("scheduled task", "---Scheduled Task: Refresh fooWebsites");
            try {
                fooWebsitesRefreshActivity.execute();
                //mHandler.postDelayed(refreshfooWebsitesRunnable,3000);
                mHandler.postDelayed(this, 3000);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                // "Unable to receive Data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                // .show();
            }
        }
    };
    startRepeatingTask();
}

void startRepeatingTask() {
    refreshfooWebsitesRunnable.run();
}
```

LOG:

```
12-14 14:56:47.624: D/scheduled task(7995): ---Scheduled Task: Refresh fooWebsites
```

And there has been no chance since yet. The UI Thread is working fine, the app won't freeze or anything like that. Why won't my runnable loop?

Comment: `fooWebsitesRefreshActivity.execute();` is this causing an exception?

Comment: no. the code is running fine and the runnable will run exactly one time and refresh the UI properly. Ill do some debugging and then update my question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why my refreshing is slower after few secounds than immediately after start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57490798/why-my-refreshing-is-slower-after-few-secounds-than-immediately-after-start)

Answer (score 1):

Try to call `mHandler.post()` instead of `refreshfooWebsitesRunnable.run()` and call a `mHandler.removeCallbacks()` in the beginning of your `run()` method.

Comment: Have you debugged/logged it? maybe `run()` is actually executing but problem is in your `fooWebsitesRefreshActivity`? Code of your activity will be helpful.