# Why my refreshing is slower after few secounds than immediately after start

Tags: java, android, handler

I am beginner in android and I am doing my test project. I have such a problem when I start the Handler method then let's say refreshing is approximately desired. But after few secounds this is slower than in the begin, immediately after clicking startGameButton

There are two handler nested to make screen refreshing.

The following code is nested in onCreate() method

```java
    final Handler handler = new Handler();

    final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            MainLoopClass mainLoop;     
            mainLoop=newMainLoopClass(HelperMethods.context,HelperMethods.rl);
            handler.postDelayed(this, 100);
        }
    };

    ...

    startGameButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            handler.postDelayed(runnable, 100);
        }
    });
```

My desired effect is to make refresh every 700 milisecounds

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems what your code have perfomance side effect
Better solution for your problem is
1. Add RxJava in your app:gradle

```
android {
    ...
}

dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.6'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.1'
    ...
}
```

add

```
val disposable = Observable.interval(700, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe {
        //refresh your UI here        
    }
```

PS:

1. If you call subscribe in MainThread

```
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
```

is not necessary

2. When you want to stop update your UI (for example in onStop) - call disposable.dispose()

Comment: in settings.gradle?

Comment: in file where you add your dependencies

Comment: add additional info to answer

Comment: click "shift" twice. enter "build". In the bottom you will see files with elephant icon. Choose build.gradle (app)

Comment: this is Kotlin. for Java replace val on Disposable

Comment: composite= Observable.interval(700, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                    .subscribe({mainLoop.run();});   There is an issue and error any tip?Exactly in .subscribe({mainLoop.run();});

Comment: Modified to:  composite= Observable.interval(700, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).subscribe(v -> mainLoop.run());

error: lambda expressions are not supported in -source 1.7
(use -source 8 or higher to enable lambda expressions)

This is strange because I have installed Jdk8

Comment: In Java for lambda you should use Retrolambda plugin or create Consumer with “new”